# Put Answer poster name at top instead of (or as well as) bottom

Tags: discussion, support, formatting

Is it just me, or do others also scroll to the bottom of especially long answers to see who the poster is?

When we get a letter posted, or email or text from an unknown source - who goes to last page to see who it is?

Why we have this odd concept escapes me.

Can we put the name at the top? Keep it at the bottom too. Some posts are sooo long you forget who wrote it!

Answer (score 2):

From a psychological perspective, I'd suggest it's better to have the name at the bottom, to avoid any internal bias of the user's name affecting how we read the Question/Answer, or worse yet - whether people upvote or downvote it. It's sort of like how well designed marking systems don't put students' names on the papers - because it can have a conscious or subconscious effect on how examiners judge their contributions.

Ideally I'd say contributions should stand on their own merit, and it's a shame when a user's identity causes us to elevate or downplay their contributions. And I think that happens to all of us.

On the other hand, I can think of a few occasions where I read a whole contribution and then get to the end and think "wow, this is better than I'd have expected from X".